# split multiple values into two columns based on single seprator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I am new to pandas.I have a situation I want to split length column into two columns a and b.Values in length column are in pair.I want to compare first pair smaller value should be in a nad larger in b.then compare next pair on same row and smaller in a,larger in b.

I have hundred rows.I think I can not use str.split because there are multiple values and same delimiter.I have no idea how to do it
The output should be same like this.
Any help will be appreciated

```
length                                            a                         b
{22.562,"35.012","25.456",37.342,24.541,38.241}   22.562,25.45624.541    35.012,37.342,38.241
{21.562,"37.012",25.256,36.342}                   31.562,25.256           37.012,36.342
{22.256,36.456,26.245,35.342,25.56,"36.25"}     22.256,26.245,25.56      36.456,35.342,36.25
```

I have tried

```html
df['a'] = df['length'].str.split(',').str[0::2]
df['b'] = df['length'].str.split(',').str[1::3]
```

through this  ode column b output is perfect but col a is printing first full pair then second.. It is not giving only 0,2,4th values

Comment: Is there a reason why your length column is a set and not a list ?

Comment: I got data as it is. actually it's raw data

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that your length column is made of set not lists.

Here is a way to do what you want by casting your length column as list:

```
df['length'] = [list(x) for x in df.length] # We cast the sets as lists
df['a'] = [x[0::2] for x in df.length]
df['b'] = [x[1::2] for x in df.length]
```

---

Output:

```
                                             length                         a  \
0  [35.012, 37.342, 38.241, 22.562, 24.541, 25.456]  [35.012, 38.241, 24.541]   
1                  [25.256, 36.342, 21.562, 37.012]          [25.256, 21.562]   
2    [35.342, 36.456, 36.25, 22.256, 25.56, 26.245]    [35.342, 36.25, 25.56]   

                          b  
0  [37.342, 22.562, 25.456]  
1          [36.342, 37.012]  
2  [36.456, 22.256, 26.245]
```

Comment: it is showing output as [{, 3, 1, 0, 3, 9, 8, 1, 8, ", 5, 3, 9, 8, 6, ...
1     [{, 3, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 2, 5, ", 5, 3, 9, 0, 3, ...

Comment: it is splitting every single digit

Comment: I have updated my question...please suggest some thing now

Comment: Can you link your raw data or a sample @user19 ?

Comment: {12140.309384148,"62651.816174354,",12475.89450012,"65841.697142563,",11417.545420764,62131.327010277}   it is the first row of  column .